# Error : Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders - cause set State in function

Tags: reactjs

Hi I Use a Function to get Date from Dayjs and I should set the value of Date in my state, but it's giving me that Error(the Error I Mentioned in my Title), it's necessary to, save the Value Of date in State because I want to POST it to Server and value of Day and Index are variable and for easy understanding to what I Exactly did, I simplified my code. how can I do what I want?

This is my Code :

```
const UserAboutPage = ( ) => {
const [Day, setDay] = useState(2);
const [Index, setindex] = useState(0);
const [TicketDay, setTicketDay] = useState();

const HandleDayDate = (Day, index) => {
    const CopyList ;
    const month = dayjs().month();
    const year = dayjs().year();
    const CurrentDayVal = dayjs().date();
    const nextTicket = Math.abs(CurrentDay - Day)
    if (Day == CurrentDay) {
      CopyList = dayjs().calendar('jalali').locale('fa').valueOf()
      setTicketDay(CopyList)
      return dayjs().calendar('jalali').locale('fa').format('dddd DD-MM')
    } else {
      if (Day < CurrentDay || Day === 6) {
        var between = 7 - nextTicket
        CopyList = dayjs(new Date(year, month, CurrentDayVal + between)).calendar('jalali').locale('fa').valueOf()
        setTicketDay(CopyList)
        return dayjs(new Date(year, month, CurrentDayVal + between)).calendar('jalali').locale('fa').format('dddd DD-MM');
      } else if (Day > CurrentDay) {
        CopyList = dayjs(new Date(year, month, CurrentDayVal + nextTicket)).calendar('jalali').locale('fa').valueOf()
        setTicketDay(CopyList)
        return dayjs(new Date(year, month, CurrentDayVal + nextTicket)).calendar('jalali').locale('fa').format('dddd DD-MM');
      }
    }
   
  }
return (
<div className="flex">
                          <span className="text-gray-500 mr-2">
                            {HandleDayDate(Day, index)}
                          </span>
                          <span className="text-green-500">
                            your Date :
                          </span>
                        </div>
)
}
```

***the User Chose Index And Day By Click On Button***

Comment: Why you re assign constant variable `CopyList`?

Comment: You made an infinite loop of render. Don't use `set state function` in `render method`.

Comment: so for what i want to do ,what do you suggest to me to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you've created an **infinite loop** of renders.
It's a common pitfall in React and is something to look out for.

What happens is the following:

1. You're calling the `HandleDayDate` function in the template.
2. `HandleDayDate`, in turn, updates the state.
3. The component is re-rendered due to the state update.
4. The template is re-assigned and calls `HandleDayDate` again.

And this cycle repeats, creating an infinite loop.

Typically, when faced with an infinite loop, the browser would freeze.
The error you are getting is due to React "catching" the problem and prevents the freeze.

Comment: i understood totally what you say when i got this Error. what can i do to set the ValueOf Date ?

Comment: If it's an action that should happen automatically when the component renders (i.e. - without user action), then you can use the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook with an empty dependency array. This should allow it to only run once.

Comment: the user chose Index and Day Buy Click on Button

Comment: In that case it's even simpler. You just need to assign it to the button's click event. Should look like this -> `<button onClick={() => handleDayDate(day, index)}>Click me!</button>`

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a function with setState inside the render method `{HandleDayDate(Day, index)}`

Because everytime react renders it will call the function which will inturn call the  `setState` method causing another re-render.

So your code will go into an infinite loop.

Bring out the logic of `setState` outside the function

Comment: So How Can I Do What I Want ?